# SQL - Fetching Multiple Results With Specific Values

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to get two or more results back with specific matches.  I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b WHERE galleryid=("555","556") limit (1,1)
```

expecting to get 2 matches, but I get an error.  Any ideas?

Clarification:  I want one result from each gallery.

Comment: Need more information. Maybe you could edit and post some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use IN instead of =.

```
SELECT * 
FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
WHERE galleryid IN ("555","556") 
limit 2
```

Edit:

Judging by your comments I think the following is what you are after.  It should get you one result for 555 and one for 556.

```
(SELECT * 
FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
WHERE galleryid = "555" 
limit 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * 
FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a, edgewe_ngg_gallery b 
WHERE galleryid = "556" 
limit 1)
```

Comment: I get "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(1,1)' at line 4 "

Comment: @NotaGuruAtAll I edited my answer.  Take a look.  Your syntax for limit is wrong. Not sure what you were trying to accomplish with that.

Comment: limit 1 works but only returns 555,  if I remove limit I get more records than I need but 556 shows up, so your answer is partially right.

Comment: @NotaGuruAtAll So are you trying to get one result for 555 and one for 556?

Comment: see my answer, the join between the 2 tables is missing.

Comment: @NotaGuruAtAll Updated my answer per your edit.  This should get you what you want I think.

Answer (score 0):

apart of the error you have shouldn't you also add some join criteria ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a
   inner join edgewe_ngg_gallery b on a.galleryid = b.galleryid    
WHERE b.galleryid IN ("555","556")
```

Otherwise you are always selecting all pictures (assuming galleryid is a column of b)

UPDATED:

```
SELECT * 
FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a
   inner join edgewe_ngg_gallery b on a.gid = b.galleryid    
WHERE  a.id in (select min(id) 
                  from edgewe_ngg_pictures p 
                 where gid in ("555","556") group by gid)
```

Comment: Makes sense but I get this error: "#1054 - Unknown column 'b.galleryid' in 'where clause' "

Comment: to which table belongs galleryid ? Is there a 1:N relation between these 2 tables ? If so, which column in pictures contains the gallery id ?

Comment: It looks like he is using MySQL.  The syntax he has works fine there.  MySQL just does some magic column selection for the join condition.

Comment: When magic is involved, I rest my case. Can't help you further then. Good luck

Comment: edgewe_ngg_gallery uses galleryid and edgewe_ngg_pictures uses gid, tried: "SELECT * FROM edgewe_ngg_pictures a inner join edgewe_ngg_gallery b on a.galleryid = b.gid WHERE b.gid IN ("555","1") limit 2" and both results come from gid '1' in with this query

Comment: Your answer just returned 2 pictures of gallery 1 which is a correct answer. remove the limit 2 to have all pictures from gallery 1 and 555

Comment: Ah, I only want 1 from each.  Sorry for not making that clear.